# How to dynamically create link with Count Bubbles in MVC with Jquery Mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Need advice from u all very badly already wasted 2 days in this. No idea what to do. I need to keep count bubbles in button in mvc4 using jquerymobile. I did it in static like

Code.

```
<div class="ui-grid-c">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "DirectPutawayDetails")'">
           DK-01
           <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">
               3
           </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="url.html" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
            DK-02
            <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">
                11
            </span>
       </a>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-c">
       <a href="url.html" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
           DK-03
           <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">12</span>
       </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-d">
      <a href="url.html" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
          DK-04
          <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">
              145
          </span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Which works great and got below output.

[image]

Now i need to generate all the button dynamically and bring similar look and feel. I used list and brought all the values to my view like below image.

But no idea how to transform the value in list to dynamic button with bubble count. Guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0KH3g Check this fiddle

I have created a temporary model and dynamically generated DIV based in the model values,try to apply this in your Model

```
@{
            string test ="";


            for(int i=0;i<@Model.countBubbleDataList.Count;i++)
            {
            string divTest="";

                divTest+="<div class='ui-block-a' style='width:25%'><a class='ui-li-has-count' data-role='button'  data-ajax='false' data-mini='true'";
                divTest+=" style='background-color:#52616D;color:white' onclick='location.href='@Url.Action('Index', 'DirectPutawayDetails')'>";
                divTest += Model.countBubbleDataList[i].Name+"<span class='ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all' style='background-color:white;color:#52616D'>3</span></a> </div></div>";

                    @Html.Raw(divTest);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a class like:

```
   <span class=" GridBubbleCount ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn- corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">

      .GridBubbleCount {
    background-color: #F7F7F8 !important;
    color: #2C343B !important;
    border-radius: 35%;
    -moz-border-radius: 35%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35%;
    height: 15%;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use partial view template? Here is the way to do it -

1. First create a partial view template for `DirectedPutaway` inside `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate` folder and name it `DirectedPutaway.cshtml`.
2. Inside this partial view define model to be `DirectedPutaway`. It is absolutely important that you should place this inside DisplayTemplate folder and name it exactly as the class name to work.
3. Then add your html and other model properties to render to the file, so the final file should look like this -

   @model DirectedPutaway

   ```
   <div class="ui-block-a">
       <a class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "DirectPutawayDetails")'">
           @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ReceivingName)
           <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color:white;color:#52616D">
               @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.NoOfMuf)
           </span>
   </a>
   </div>
   ```
4. Ok, so far we have the template and since it is createed inside shared displaytemplate and has proper name, its really easy to use it. Just after getting the list add a line to render the list, MVC will automatically look for the template and render it -

   ```
   @{

       var myPutaway = (List<DirectedPutaway>)ViewBag.DirectePutaway;
   }
   <div class="ui-grid-c">
       @Html.DisplatFor(m=> myPutaway)
   <div>
   ```

This is probably the most recommended MVC way.

Finally, If you want to know how display templates and editor templates work in ASP.Net MVC, you can checkout the doc here, these two blogs show how to use templates. -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html